# Python dictionary creation with conditioned values added

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

I want to make a dictionary from 2 numpy arrays, `arr1` as keys of dictionary and `arr2` as values of dictionary. The problem I encountered is the fact that I don't want to simply add values to the keys in that order, but to add a specific value if a condition to a key, element of `arr1` is fullfiled. For that, I have another numpy array `arr3` with one more element than `arr1` and `arr2` and if a key is between actual index and next element of `arr3`, `[i,i+1)` the value with corresponding index to the actual one will be the value paired to the actual key.

For example:

```
dict = {}
arr1 = np.array([0,9])
arr2 = np.array([0,5])
arr3 = np.array([0,5,10])
..
```

the dict should be {0:0,9:5}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boundsWithKeyValues = zip(arr3[:-1], arr3[1:], arr1, arr2)
result = {k: v for kMin, kMax, k, v in boundsWithKeyValues if kMin <= k <= kMax}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be one option. Perhaps it could be done with less code.

```
import numpy as np

dict_ = {}
arr1 = np.array([0,9])
arr2 = np.array([0,5])
arr3 = np.array([0,5,10])

for i,(k,v) in enumerate(zip(arr1, arr2)):
    if arr3[i] <= arr1[i] and arr1[i] < arr3[i+1]:
        dict_[k] = v
```